# Differences between 记得 and 记住

Tags: difference, synonyms, verbs

Google obviously doesn't help, both recorded as remember / recall except 记得 as `bring to mind` and 记住 as `bear in mind`.

Found [a blog post](https://hinative.com/zh-CN/questions/6442593) that is confusing with some claiming 记得 is more about having done the act of remembering.

I found another one with the opposite view [here](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/542573#answer-1327759), but I recall learning 记得 early on and its meanings included the act of remembering, including a bit of confusion due to some overlap with 想起来 (outside of scope here).

I'd love outside confirmation and possibly a few example sentences using both 记得 and 记住.

Answer (score 5):

The biggest help to clarify the difference is that 记住 has the result complement 住, which is used to express **halt** (e.g. 站住 stand still), and, by extension, **firmness** of the action (e.g. 忍住 withstand).

So 记住 literally means "remember firmly", therefore *"bear in mind"*, with also the additional nuance of making an active attempt to remember.

Examples:

> 他刚说的话很重要，你一定要记住 = What he just said is very important, you must remember it.
>
> 中文语法例外太多，我记不住 = Chinese grammar has too many exceptions, I can't remember them.

记得 instead means simply "to remember", "to recall", without an active effort to remember firmly.

Examples:

> 我昨天晚饭吃了什么，我已经不记得了 = I already don't remember what I had for dinner yesterday
>
> 明天记得把垃圾扔掉吧 = remember to take out the trash tomorrow
>
> 你去超市记得给我买一些水果 = remember to buy me some fruit when you go to the market